# Livecharts: ColumnSerie next to a StackedColumnSerie

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I use LiveCharts in WPF, C#, and I try to show a single ColumnSerie next to a StackedColumnSerie, but both series are shown behind each other. How can I show these two Columns side by side? And by the way, is it possible to use more than one StackedColumn in a chart (for example value 1, 2 as stacked and values 3 and 4 as another stacked column?

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem, the sad answer is that this is currently not possible.

After delving into the code, it seems that in the next version there will be the possibility to group series to achieve the effect you want. The functionality is already implemented, there is just no release yet.